Cannot register a site from the Configuration Checklist using the "Register a site" menu option
I am trying to register our CiviCRM site (currently running CiviCRM 5.75.2 on Wordpress), but keep getting the following message:
"Sorry, we encountered an error! See console log for more details."
The screenshot below shows the screen I see.  I have tried several times, each time with the same result.  How do I register our CiviCRM site?  The error message is generated by the https://civicrm.org/register-a-site web page.

Hi, is the error displayed when you submit the form, or when it initially displays? Thank you for reporting this!

The error occurs every time I click the Submit button.
